# Java: Default value for split function

Tags: java

I have this code...

```
Donor newDonor = new Donor(null,
                donor.getName().split(" ")[0],
                donor.getName().split(" ")[1],
                address);
```

The problem is I am not allowed to change donor to have separate fields of first name and surname. So now the above code requires a surname. What if they don't enter it. Shall I do an if statement, if so how? Or is there a way to define a default value. So if they don't enter a surname, the default is nothing (`""`). Please advice.

Comment: If `split` only returns an array containing one element, is that the first name or last name?

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: The easiest way to guarantee there are at least two elements is to append an elements: `(name + " ").split(" ", -1)[1]`. Note the -1 is necessary to avoid stripping trailing empty tokens.

Comment: Full name can start with last name like mine :) so you can not just say index 0 is first name, if you have this kind of structure then this will break your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String[] names = donor.getName().split(" ");
 String first = names[0];
 String last = names.length > 1? names[1] : "";

 Donor newDonor = new Donor(null, first, last, address);
```

If for whatever reasons you want the check in params of constructor

```
 Donor newDonor = new Donor(null,
            donor.getName().split(" ")[0],
            donor.getName().split(" ").length >1 ?  donor.getName().split(" ")[1]: "",
            address);
```

Comment: Possible but will be very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space at the end, and care about it (`-1` in split function) in case there is only one word

```
String[] names = (fullName + " ").split("\\s+", -1);
Donor newDonor = new Donor(null, names[0], names[1], "address");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to create a sort of adapter class to do the dirt work. Something like this:

```
    public class DonorAdapter {

        private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "xyz";
        private static final String DELIMITER = " ";

        private String name;
        private String surnameName;

        public DonorAdapter(Donor donor) {

            String[] s = donor.getName().split(DELIMITER);
            name = s.length - 1 >= 0 ? s[0] : DEFAULT_NAME;
            surnameName = s.length - 1 >= 1 ? s[1] : DEFAULT_NAME;
        }

        public String getName() { return name; }
        public String getSurname() { return surnameName; }
    }
```

Then your code would be simpler and IMO more elegant.

```
DonorAdapter adapter = new DonorAdapter(donor);

Donor newDonor = new Donor(null, adapter.getName(), adapter.getSurname(), address);
```